# Remove lines of a file after the N firsts lines but before to integer number

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I have a file like this:

```
    1         2         3         4         5
 0.05775  0.00238  0.02514   0.00469  0.01882
 0.26868  0.04114  0.09359  0.02155  0.01367
 0.11413  0.00907  0.04032  0.02487   0.01156
 0.03759  0.00624  0.00819  0.01527   0.01128
 0.09910  0.03416  0.02280  0.00627   0.00433
    6         7         8         9        10
0.01798   0.00035   0.00672  0.02180  0.00184
0.01880  0.00834   0.04975  0.05503   0.00234
0.00242  0.00618   0.04936  0.02320   0.00269
 0.00931  0.00611   0.02371  0.00299   0.00353
 0.00763  0.00197  0.00673  0.00338   0.00182
   11        12        13        14        15
 0.00330   0.00521   0.00495   0.00426   0.00403
0.01121   0.02891   0.02162   0.02235   0.01534
0.01081   0.01871   0.00888   0.01835   0.00867
0.00684   0.00965   0.00645   0.00802   0.00317
0.00671   0.00333   0.00376  0.00204   0.00028
```

This example contains three main blocks of information. The first row
of each block contains always an integer number, while the others rows
contains decimal numbers. I want to take the first 4 rows of each block.

Output:

```
    1         2         3         4         5
 0.05775  0.00238  0.02514   0.00469  0.01882
 0.26868  0.04114  0.09359  0.02155  0.01367
 0.11413  0.00907  0.04032  0.02487   0.01156
    6         7         8         9        10
0.01798   0.00035   0.00672  0.02180  0.00184
0.01880  0.00834   0.04975  0.05503   0.00234
0.00242  0.00618   0.04936  0.02320   0.00269
   11        12        13        14        15
 0.00330   0.00521   0.00495   0.00426   0.00403
0.01121   0.02891   0.02162   0.02235   0.01534
0.01081   0.01871   0.00888   0.01835   0.00867
```

I was trying to do something with sed but, with no sucess.

Comment: Do all blocks have one header line and *exactly* five lines of data?  Or do some rows have variable amounts?

Comment: Hi @Wildcard. All blocks has a header line and N lines of data (here, I post 5 lines as an example ). But always the N lines is constant.

Comment: And, do all blocks have at *least* three lines after the header?

Comment: yes! at least three lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked:

> Do all blocks have one header line and *exactly* five lines of data?  Or do some rows have variable amounts?

If it's *exactly* 6 lines per block, you can use:

```
sed -n 'N;N;N;p;N;N' file.txt
```

But if not, then use:

```
sed -n '/\./!{N;N;N;p;}' file.txt
```

The latter command, on encountering a line without any periods, will print that and the following three lines (without checking them for periods).  It will then skip the following lines until another is encountered that doesn't have periods.

---

If you can, I recommend fixing the tool that's providing this data so it gives it in a more sensible format.

Comment: Great @Wildcard.  What happen if I need to print many lines (30 for example) after a line without period. Does it possible to do something like sed -n '/\./!{30 lines;p;}' file.txt

Comment: sed '/\./!{N;N;N;p};d' infile. for 30 put 30 N or with awk: awk -v 'a=30' '!/\./{print;for(i=1;i<=a;i++){getline;print}}' infile

Comment: OK, your solution with awk is what I was trying to found. Thanks @ctac_

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v RS='\n  ' '{
   count=split($0,lines,/\n/);
   lines[1]="  "lines[1];
   max=4 ; if (count < max) { max = count };
   for (i=1; i <= max; i++) print lines[i];
  }' input 
     1         2         3         4         5
0.05775  0.00238  0.02514   0.00469  0.01882
0.26868  0.04114  0.09359  0.02155  0.01367
0.11413  0.00907  0.04032  0.02487   0.01156
    6         7         8         9        10
0.01798   0.00035   0.00672  0.02180  0.00184
0.01880  0.00834   0.04975  0.05503   0.00234
0.00242  0.00618   0.04936  0.02320   0.00269
   11        12        13        14        15
0.00330   0.00521   0.00495   0.00426   0.00403
0.01121   0.02891   0.02162   0.02235   0.01534
0.01081   0.01871   0.00888   0.01835   0.00867
```

This `awk` script make use of the fact that the header lines for each block start with at least two spaces, while the data lines don't.  If we set the record separator (`RS`) to a newline followed by two spaces, we can process each block individually.

Each block is then split into into individual lines.  The first line has two space characters pre-pended (to replace the spaces eaten up by the record separator), and then the first 4 lines are printed (or less, if there happens to be less than 4 lines in a block).